# load file js offline (local node_modules)

Tags: angular, node-modules

I've installed ng2-google-charts, but loader.js is being uploaded at https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js. How to change to LOCAL?

I tried to change the file  /home/kleber/angular/escola/node_modules/ng2-google-charts/google-charts-loader.service.js

```
    GoogleChartsLoaderService.prototype.loadGoogleChartsScript = function () {
            var _this = this;
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                if (resolve === void 0) { resolve = Function.prototype; }
                if (reject === void 0) { reject = Function.prototype; }
                if (typeof google !== 'undefined' && google.charts) {
                    resolve();
                }
                else if (!_this.googleScriptIsLoading) {
                    _this.googleScriptIsLoading = true;
                    var script = document.createElement('script');
                    script.type = 'text/javascript';
<-----------------------------------HERE ------------------>
                    //script.src = 'https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js';
                    script.src = './loader.js';
<-----------------------------------HERE ------------------>
                    script.async = true;
                    script.defer = true;
                    script.onload = function () {
                        _this.googleScriptIsLoading = false;
                        _this.googleScriptLoadingNotifier.emit(true);
                        resolve();
                    };
                    script.onerror = function () {
                        _this.googleScriptIsLoading = false;
                        _this.googleScriptLoadingNotifier.emit(false);
                        reject();
                    };
                    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
                }
                else {
                    _this.googleScriptLoadingNotifier.subscribe(function (loaded) {
                        if (loaded) {
                            resolve();
                        }
                        else {
                            reject();
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        };
```

[image: Error console]

Comment: Check your path for accessing the loader.js

Answer (score 1):

I have searched and didn't find offline js.
Google terms of service do not allow you to download the google.charts.load or google.visualization code to use offline.

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/faq